# Looking to identify this 3-pin connector

Tags: connector, pins

These connectors are from a Blackburn X8SL mountain bike light system.  The sheathing is rotting and I am looking for replacement wiring and connectors.  I search for 3-pin IP67 type connectors and cannot really find an exact match. This would not really be the end of the world if it were not for these connectors needing to fit into the battery pack.

[image]

The wires running to the connector ends are quite small, maybe 22 AWG.

Comment: Please provide dimensions

Answer (score 2):

Wesiri "big size".

I found it with my [Identiconn connector identification utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=led_lighting_circ_conn&s=big%20size).

You can buy directly from Wesiri through [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2251832807285899.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt) as well as on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Wesiri+%22big+size%22).